# Python: make scipy use numpy.float128 instead numpy.float64?

Tags: python, numpy, types, scipy

Is it possible, and if yes how to do it: How can I make scipy use by default numpy.float128. For example

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> type(norm.pdf(10, 10, 1))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

and I want it to be

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> type(norm.pdf(10, 10, 1))
<class 'numpy.float128'>
```

If not, I will need to implement norm.pdf function by myself, which is easy, but do not solve my problem.

Comment: maybe this could help? http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2013-February/034063.html

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can't.  Some of the scipy routines are wrappers of code written in C or Fortran that are only available in double precision.  Even if you figure out which ones are pure python+numpy, and manage to ensure that the operations performed in the computation preserve the data type, you'll find that many of the functions use hardcoded 64 bit constants such as `numpy.pi`.